# Very precise timer for C? So precise to measure single function call

Tags: c, performance, time, benchmarking

I would like to measure execution time of some math function in C. (I have a library which computes lots of math and I would like to know how much time single call would take).

For now on, I use `getrusage` or `GetProcessTimes` and `clock_gettime/gettimeofday` or `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` but they're no precise enough, when I measure single call they always show 0...

I know I can do 'x' function calls but then I would have an average time. Is there any precise timer for C Win/Lin, so precise that would be able to measure a single function call wall/cpu time?

I can't use `boost` (its pure C), I also know abou this (still not enough precise):

```
clock_t start = clock();
/*Do something*/
clock_t end = clock();
float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

and this (same as above):

```
  time_t start,end;
  double dif;
  time (&start);
  // Do some calculation.
  time (&end);
  dif = difftime (end,start);
```

and even tried this: `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. Also, I know that I shouldnt use `rdtsc` to measure time. What else can I do?

Comment: `gettimeofday`, or `clock_gettime`.

Comment: It's better to call the function in a loop and take the average, otherwise you may get errors to due interrupts and other factors.

Comment: @KerrekSB: something more precise? So precise like profilers-way?

Comment: @nullpointer: More precise than nanoseconds?! Hmm....

Comment: @KerrekSB: so how do profilers implement such thing?

Comment: @nullpointer: Profilers typically *sample* a subset of all calls, e.g. they check every so often in which function the execution is currently taking place. They don't count *every* call.

Comment: what's wrong with rdtsc as long as your cpu supports `constant or invariant TSC`?

Comment: @nullpointer It's important to distinguish between *precise* (which nanos should be plenty for) and *accurate* (which as Paul R noted, can be affected by interrupts and, for example, cache state). Run your function a large number of times to improve accuracy.

Comment: @KerrekSB: could you please show a pseudocode for it? I would like to understand it well :)

Comment: What's the argument against [performance counters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter)? Portability? If so, what kind of portability are you aiming for? Only C standard library calls? Would one solution that works on Windows and another that works on Linux be acceptable, assuming proper preprocessor switches for conditional inclusion of the appropriate one?

Comment: The thing your computer tries to tell you is that single function call is so fast, it doesn't even register as a blip. You've wasted more time writing this post and thinking about this than your function ever did.

Comment: This looks like a bad case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to loop many iterations. Rarely are even performance counters accurate enough to measure a single call to a small function. What you might also want to know is that all those fancy performance counters are usually implemented using the `rdtsc` which you are trying to avoid. Furthermore, `rdtsc` has a significant overhead and is probably itself more expensive than a call to a trivial function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of time stamps, you will likely want to take a look on how to access hardware specific performance counters. Assuming Windows platform, you might want to take a look at [HCP Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd796399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).